# What is the most standard way of ignoring output from a python's function?

Tags: python

Let's say that I have function `foo` that returns a single output.
I do not make use of that output in the caller of the function `foo`.

What is the most elegant way to handle this?

```
r = foo()
# r is not used anywhere later.
```

Or should I just not do any assignment when calling `foo()`?
The only thing is that I probably get lint warning if I do this.

```
foo()
....
```

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine. Just don't assign the output to anything.

Comment: What does `foo` do or return? Some people think that methods that return something shouldn't have side-effects. Does it just print something?

Comment: If you don't need to use the output, just don't use it. What's the problem?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 My concern is a lint warning.

Comment: Some warnings direct your attention to actual issues with your code, which you must resolve. This is not one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ignore the output:

```
foo()
```

Another option (which personally, I don't like too much) is assign the output to a variable '_':

```
_ = foo()
```

This is a conventional way to say that the returned value is ignored / unneeded, and is usually used in `for` loops:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
for _ in lst:
    # do something unrelated to the current element in the list
    print 'hi'
```

Comment: The first and third code are okay. The 2nd you stated " I don't like too much" which I agree with and don't think its even worth mentioning (unless unpacking multiple variables eg. `a, _ = items`. However also keep in mind even the use of `_` is no longer recommended because it can conflict with the django translation `_`

Comment: I only mentioned option #2 because OP said option #1 would "probably get lint warning". In case that turned out to be true, I gave the 2nd option. The 3rd code is there to show where option #2 is usually used. In any case, I was unaware `_` had special meaning in `Django`. I'll be sure to look into that. Thank you.